# PayPal iOS App using MPL - Authentication fail

Tags: authentication, mobile, paypal

I'm trying to use PayPal SDK to use it on iOS App, using MPL, like described on here:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mpl-itemPayment-iOS/

the only changes I made on simple App demo project, is to change the currency, from USD to EUR.

But every time I try to do the login to pay, I receive the message "Login failed, please try again". My login is ok because it works on the web site.

This error occurs on the ENV_SANDBOX and ENV_LIVE also. I'm testing the app on iPAD and also in the simulator.

I really don't know what to do, someone have some idea?

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem on Android and I am using MPL version 1.5.5.44. According to the PayPal developer support, some certificates for old library versions have expired recently. The latest versions (both iOS and Android) are available from here:

https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/tree/gh-pages/MPL

Hope it helped.

Comment: Even though I'm using the latest mpl library, the problem still exists. I can't login, everytime it prompts "Login Failed, Please try again" :/ ..

Comment: Viktor +1. This is the main issue with the login failed. Download the new Library and integrated it. It will work just fine.